# Magento Custom Report

Tags: php, magento, report, magento-1.8

I am trying to create a custom report I have successfully created but I am not able to get use of filter values such as period(day/month/year). When its day its shows perfect result but when its month and year it reduces result.

my files details 
Block\Adminhtml\Commissionreport.php

```
<?php  

class Magestore_Commissionreport_Block_Adminhtml_Commissionreport extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container {

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_commissionreport';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'commissionreport';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('commissionreport')->__('Commission Report');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton('add');
  }

}
```

Block\Adminhtml\Commissionreport\Grid.php

```
<?php

class Magestore_Commissionreport_Block_Adminhtml_Commissionreport_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid
{
  public function __construct()
  {         
      parent::__construct();
      $this->setId('commissionreportGrid');
      $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
      $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
      $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);  
  }

  protected function _prepareCollection()
  {     

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        // Get the data collection from the model
        $this->getCollection()->initReport('commissionreport/commissionreport');
  }

  protected function _prepareColumns()
  {
      $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('commissionreport')->__('Created At'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'sortable'  => true,        
          'index'     => 'created_at',
      ));

      $this->addColumn('order_id', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('commissionreport')->__('Order Id'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'sortable'  => true,        
          'index'     => 'order_id',
      ));     

      $this->addColumn('fullname', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('commissionreport')->__('Customer Name'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'width'     =>'550px',
          'index'     => 'fullname',
      ));     

      $this->addColumn('total_commission', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('commissionreport')->__('Commission Earned'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'total'     =>'sum',
          'width'     =>'350px',
          'index'     => 'total_commission',
      ));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('commissionreport')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('commissionreport')->__('XML'));

      return parent::_prepareColumns();
  }



  public function getRowUrl($row)
  {
      return false;
  }



}
```

Commissionreport\controllers\Adminhtml\CommissionreportController.php

```
<?php
class Magestore_Commissionreport_Adminhtml_CommissionreportController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    protected function _initAction() { 
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('rewards/rewards')
            ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Rewards Transaction'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Rewards Transaction'));
        return $this;
    }   

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_initAction()
            ->renderLayout();       
    }
}
```

Commissionreport\Model\Commissionreport.php

```
<?php
class Magestore_Commissionreport_Model_Commissionreport extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{

protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('rewards/rewards');
    }

    protected function _joinFields($from = '', $to = '')
    {
        $firstnameAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'firstname');
        $lastnameAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('1', 'lastname');
        $this->getSelect()
                ->join( array('order_item'=> sales_flat_order_item), 'order_item.quote_item_id = main_table.item_id', array('order_item.created_at'))
                ->join( array('quote_item'=> sales_flat_quote_item), 'quote_item.item_id = main_table.item_id', array('quote_item.commission', 'quote_item.product_id', 'quote_item.qty'));     
            $this->addFieldToFilter('order_item.created_at' , array("from" => $from, "to" => $to, "datetime" => false));
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDateRange($from, $to)
    {
        $this->_reset()
        ->_joinFields($from, $to);
        return $this;
    }
    public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

When I select month it shows perfect result will all records

[image]

but when we select month or year it reduces the result

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions about Magento should be asked on the dedicated Stack Exchange site: [magento.se]

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your controller from Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Report_Abstract and use this code in indexAction():

```
$gridBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('your_report_name.grid');
$filterFormBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('your_report_filter_name');

$this->_initReportAction(array(
            $gridBlock,
            $filterFormBlock
        ));
```

_initReportAction() assigns filter data to blocks passed in params.

You may also have a look at Mage_Adminhtml_Report_ProductController::viewedAction() for the detailed usage example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add function

```
public function setPageSize()
{
    return $this;
}
```

to your model. Because in core has function

```
 public function countTotals($grid, $from, $to)
{
    $columns = array();
    foreach ($grid->getColumns() as $col) {
        $columns[$col->getIndex()] = array("total" => $col->getTotal(), "value" => 0);
    }

    $count = 0;
    $report = $grid->getCollection()->getReportFull($from, $to);
    foreach ($report as $item) {
        if ($grid->getSubReportSize() && $count >= $grid->getSubReportSize()) {
            continue;
        }
        $data = $item->getData();

        foreach ($columns as $field=>$a) {
            if ($field !== '') {
                $columns[$field]['value'] = $columns[$field]['value'] + (isset($data[$field]) ? $data[$field] : 0);
            }
        }
        $count++;
    }
    $data = array();
    foreach ($columns as $field => $a) {
        if ($a['total'] == 'avg') {
            if ($field !== '') {
                if ($count != 0) {
                    $data[$field] = $a['value']/$count;
                } else {
                    $data[$field] = 0;
                }
            }
        } else if ($a['total'] == 'sum') {
            if ($field !== '') {
                $data[$field] = $a['value'];
            }
        } else if (strpos($a['total'], '/') !== FALSE) {
            if ($field !== '') {
                $data[$field] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    $totals = new Varien_Object();
    $totals->setData($data);

    return $totals;
}
```

$count >= $grid->getSubReportSize() default is 5.